# Port available to set in docker-compose.yml for mysql and wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker-compose, port

I have an application where i can create several wordpress project each one with a docker-compose.yml file to launch a local wordpress env.

I setted:

mysql:
ports:
- 8081:3306

wordpress
ports:
- 8080:80

I would like to each project has a unique port configuration to allow launch all if i need it or to dont use a used port and return an error.

So, what range of ports are available to use for mysql and wordpress?

Do you know if it is possible or is a bad idea?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally possible! The trick is to only specify the port that is internal to the container. Then, when docker-compose boots up, it'll automatically assign a host port mapping to the internal container port.

For instance, if you define your docker-compose.yaml like so:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql
        ports:
            - 3306
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=badpassworddontdothis
    wordpress:
        image: wordpress
        ports:
            - 80
```

And run `docker-compose up`, we can look at the port mappings that were assigned:

```
❯ docker-compose ps
        Name                      Command               State                 Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
67077886_mysql_1       docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      0.0.0.0:55362->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
67077886_wordpress_1   docker-entrypoint.sh apach ...   Up      0.0.0.0:55361->80/tcp
```

This shows that you can access the mysql container on host port 55362, and wordpress on port 55361.

If you need to programatically get the exposed port for a given service, you can run:

```
❯ docker-compose port wordpress 80
0.0.0.0:55361
```

and you'll get back the ip/port pair that will allow you to talk to wordpress container port 80:

```
❯ curl -v $(docker-compose port wordpress 80)
*   Trying 0.0.0.0...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 55361 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 0.0.0.0:55361
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Tue, 13 Apr 2021 20:09:03 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.16
< Location: http://0.0.0.0:55361/wp-admin/setup-config.php
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
* Connection #0 to host 0.0.0.0 left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

(The 302 is because I didn't actually set up wordpress, but it's still a response from the server so it counts).

Comment: After probe it a couple of days. The problem comes when I install wordpress in the liberated ports and then, restart the laptop. When I type docker-compose ps the ports have been changed and the installation is broken.

I think the best solution is save first port assignation to docker-compose.yml no? Do you know another solution?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah this'll generate new host ports every time the container starts up. It's the only real way to guarantee that your containers won't have port mapping collisions, unless you want to keep track of assigned ports yourself.

If you want to keep track of ports assigned yourself, you can change the `- 80` to be `- <assigned_port>:80` (same for mysql ports), but you'll need to manage each of your docker-compose files and make sure they have different assigned ports.

Alternatively, you can use the `docker-compose port wordpress 80` command to figure out the assigned port when you need it